# JCombo Box with mySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtextfield, jcombobox

I have a JCombo Box with 2 values (Fanta, Cola) and a JTextfield. If i write a number in the JTextfield and choose for example Fanta it should add the value in the MYSQL database in the colummn Fanta, if i choose Cola it should add it in Cola. I already have a database connection and i made a function where i can add 1 at a time but not by choosing in the JComboBox.

I am a Beginner in Java and a non-native speaker and i searched for hours on this topic but could not find anything.

Comment: You have to implement an action listener and in its main method `actionPerfomed` execute the insert into the DB https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners

Comment: I thought of the process something like this: Choose the drink, enter the value and pressing the submit button. Wouldn't the solution you suggested write the values in the database in the instant you select your drink?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem? That will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue.

Comment: I don't have any code related to the problem, i can't think of any method this could work so i could not even started programming, i am sorry.